# How can I tell Visual Studio to NOT BREAK on a particular exception?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, exception

I have a particular type of exception that I would like Visual Studio to **not break on** and show the Exception Assistant screen.  Essentially I would like it just to let my normal exception handling infrastructure deal with it.

The exception is an inheritor of System.Exception which I wrote and have the source code for.  Any where this is thrown I want VS to not catch it, ie it is not useful to just supress a single throw new BlahException();  in code.  This is because the exception is thrown a lot, and I don't want to have to supress every single instance individually.

In case it makes a difference I am on Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate, Framework 3.5 SP1.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Go to the Debug menu and select Exceptions.  Select add and type in your exception.  This will add a checkbox item for your exception. Anytime that exception is thrown your debugger will pause if that checkbox is on.  Make sure in your case that this checkbox is unchecked.

One thing though is that your exception will still be thrown and caught in any try/catch blocks you have in your actual code.

Comment: That's interesting, not seen that screen before.  However, i want the debugger to not pause, if you amend your reply I can give you the answer :)

Comment: Yes, the behaviour I want is for my try-catch blocks to handle the exception without the debugger popping up.

Comment: Is there any way to specify in code like DebuggerStepThrough? The solution above has one disadvantage: when I uncheck the checkbox to break on exception and then check it again, all exceptions will be checked again, including the unwanted one.

Comment: In VS2015, that panel is under Debug > Windows > Exception Settings